# git log fails if I use --graph --decorate and --oneline options

Tags: git

I have a repository with a single commit.

`git log --graph --decorate --oneline` displays nothing.

This problem only exists if I have all three options -- `--graph`, `--decorate`, and `--oneline`.  If I have only two of the three, it works properly.

Why would this be?

Comment: Using `git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)` this works as expected, which version are you running?

Comment: I'm using git 2.11.0 on windows and it works fine (even with a single commit on a single branch on the repo)

Comment: I am using git version 2.12.2.windows.2

Answer (score 0):

Your case is rarely, because your Git repository has only 1 commit. Git is version control, therefore, you should test with repository has at least 2 commits. With 1 commit, drawing graph maybe impossible.

Solution: Try more few commits, at better, has few branches. Then, try

```
git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate
```

or run `git log` with per single parameter.